I am having an issue with google maps where I am using flutter framework. The code does not contain any errors yet it does not display the map
Itried using the google maps in dart/flutter but it does not display the map on my device. I had used maps with kotlin and worked out just fine. Can anyone help me with that?image of output logs.
You can also go through my repo. https:Github.com/wamitinewton/flexfit
I tried checking my configuration in the Androidmanifest.xml but everything seems to be well configured

Please provide a small code snippet which causes the code and please upload images as images instead of a link and if images only contain text, then please upload the text instead.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
